# Question about assembly

Tags: syntax, assembly

```
.text
    .globl main
main:
     xorl %eax,%eax ;return 0
     ret
```

Like such a tiny programe:

1.is it true that `indentation is just personal preference`?

2.the complete of assembly is of various `.tags` and `func:`, is there any other part missing that can no be included in these two categories?

Comment: The answers depend on what assembler you are using.

Comment: @Paul R,for all assembly I know of ,it seems to be the same.

Comment: @new_perl: different assemblers can have different rules about the relative placement of labels and directives, etc - e.g. with some assemblers labels must start in column 1 whereas others may be more flexible.

Comment: @Paul R ,the `labels` in assembly **always** maps to `function` in c,right? Is there any other ingredient besides these two ?

Comment: @R__: no, labels can be local or global and may or may not correspond to function entry points (although the converse is true of course, every entry point needs a label).

Comment: @Paul R ,oh I see that. Is there any other ingredient besides tags and labels in assembly?

Comment: "Tags" is a bit of a misnomer - in a full-featured assembler though you might have *labels*, *directives*, *equates*, *macros*, *pseudo-instructions*, and sometimes interesting high level extensions for supporting things like loops and conditionals, structures and even OOP.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, I do think indentation is just to make it easy for you and other people to read your program.
2. "func : " are labels which act as a way of helping you reference difference parts of your program. It helps a lot when doing loops and such.
   ".tags" or ".globl" are directives, these are used by the assembler when assembling your code to machine instructions.

Comment: Are there any other parts besides tags and labels?

Comment: not that I'm aware of. I'm still learning assembly language though.